# How can I transfer songs between Garageband for iOS and OS X?

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, music, garageband

I have Garageband on iPad, iPhone and OS X. How can I transfer the music between them? I have enabled iCloud with iPad and iPhone but cannot understand how to get the music from there to OS X? I have tried iTunes and the file sharing option, but it is too slow, I am trying to find some faster way — I want that the sounds to be available between all of my devices without too many manual changes, hopefully automatically.

Basically: I create a song with the iPhone or iPad, I want it immediately available on OS X for processing, how to get it there?

Comment: ...perhaps related [here](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/5405/mixing-videos-and-sounds-with-garageband-soundcloud-and-youtube).

Comment: WHY can't I just e-mail the song to myself? Sometimes I hate all the restrictions with Apple.

Comment: @Marcus Email really is awful for large attachments and Apple does sync all the iOS songs to the Mac. If you have a case where the selected answer here doesn't work for you, you could ask a follow on question explaining how this solution doesn't work for you (or your use case is different than the one hhh has described).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a quicker way here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/20126598#20126598

Basically, in ~/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXX~com~apple~mobilegarageband you'll find the songs you've saved in iCloud from GarageBand on iOS.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you've got **iCloud** turned on in **Garageband**, by tapping the **+** icon when viewing all your songs. Then, for sending a song to iCloud, just:

1. Tap on the *Edit* button, and select all the songs you want.
2. You will now see an iCloud icon along the top bar. Tapping it, will prompt you to send the songs to iCloud.

Now, all uploaded songs to iCloud will have an iCloud logo on the top-right corner of the song thumbnail.

Opening Garageband with any other device, which has, too, iCloud enabled, will show a green arrow on the top-right corned of the songs which **haven't** yet been downloaded. Tapping the thumbnail will start the download.

Mind that, songs created with iOS's version of Garageband **cannot** be opened with the OS X application if it's the 6.0.1 or earlier version.

Comment: ...so I need to wait just for newer iOS version?

Comment: The other way round. Updating the Mac version to **6.0.2** should let you open the songs you've created with iOS.

Comment: Ok, not yet available for me so have to wait...

Answer (score 1):

This is my clear impression: You can't.

iOS Garageband *can* use the iCloud. OS X Garageband *can not*. Use iCloud for moving between Garagebands on iOS-devices only.